# I need to know how to get the last chars of some Strings

Tags: sas

I got this chars 
DDSPRJ11 
DDSPRJ12
DDSPRJ12
DDRJCT

in the case of the first 3 i want the last 4 chars e the case of the last i want the last 3 chars, how can i get them using substr and get them in the correct order eg: RJ11.

Comment: Is the condition of how many suffix characters you want dependent on the prefix characters (`DDSP` vs `DDR`) ? What should be done for rogue values such as `DDSPRJ1729` or `DDREXTREME` ? Is the focus more concerned with removing the prefix or detecting and extracting a suffix ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with regular expression matching using `prxchange`:

```
data have;
infile datalines;
input mystr $ @@;
datalines;
DDSPRJ11 DDSPRJ12 DDSPRJ12 DDRJCT
;
run;

data want;
  set have;
  suffix = prxchange('s/(DDSP|DDR)(.*)/$2/', 1, mystr);
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

@user667489 is perfect answer if it you have can read all of values separately. if it is in same variable as shown below you can use the same code given by @user667489. and add can add can function. prxnext, can also be used to achieve the same. both examples are shown below

```
data have;
 val= "DDSPRJ11 DDSPRJ12 DDSPRJ12 DDRJCT";
 run;

/* using prxchange with scan*/
 data want;
set have;
suffix = prxchange('s/(DDSP|DDR)//', -1, val);
 do i = 1 to countw(suffix,' ');
 newstr= scan(suffix, i);
output;
 end;
 drop suffix val;
 run;

/* using prxposn*/

 data want;
length val1 re $200.;
 set have;
start = 1;
stop = length(val);

re = prxparse('/(DDSP|DDR)/');
set have;
call prxnext(re, start, stop, trim(val), position, length);
  do while (position > 0);
     val1 = substr(val, position+length, length);
     call prxnext(re, start, stop, trim(val), position, length);
     output;
  end;
drop re start stop position length val;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it in a simple python.
I assumed that, you want last 4 char of every word except last.

string_1 = 'DDSPRJ11 DDSPRJ12 DDSPRJ12 DDRJCT'

list_string = string_1.split()

new_list = []

for i in range(len(list_string)):

if i == len(list_string) - 1:

```
new_list.append(list_string[i][-3:])
```

else:

```
new_list.append(list_string[i][-4:])
```

print(new_list)

output:
['RJ11', 'RJ12', 'RJ12', 'JCT']